# Understanding class variables in Java

Tags: java, data-structures

The following is a simple Linked List from a popular YouTube [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=195KUinjBpU).

```java
public class Link {

   public String bookName;
   public int millionsSold;

   public Link next;

   public Link(String bookName, int millionsSold) {
      this.bookName = bookName;
      this.millionsSold = millionsSold;
   }

   @Override 
   public String toString() {
       return bookName;
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      LinkList theLinkedList = new LinkList();

      theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Don Quixote", 500);
      theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("A Tale of Two Cities", 200);
      theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("The Lord of the Rings", 150);
      theLinkedList.insertFirstLink("Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone", 107);

      theLinkedList.removeLink("A Tale of Two Cities");
      System.out.println("\nA Tale of Two Cities Removed\n");
   }
}

class LinkList {
   public Link firstLink;

   LinkList() {
      firstLink = null;
   }

   public void insertFirstLink(String bookName, int millionsSold) {
      Link newLink = new Link(bookName, millionsSold);
      newLink.next = firstLink;
      firstLink = newLink;
   }

   public Link removeLink(String bookName) {

      Link currentLink = firstLink;
      Link previousLink = firstLink;

      while (currentLink.bookName != bookName) {
         if (currentLink.next == null) 
            return null;
         else {
            previousLink = currentLink;
            currentLink = currentLink.next;
         }
       }

      if (currentLink == firstLink) 
        firstLink = firstLink.next;
      else {
        previousLink.next = currentLink.next;
      }
      return currentLink;
   }
}
```

I am having trouble in understanding the `removeLink` method of `LinkedList` class. After executing the statement `previousLink.next = currentLink.next` in that method, why are the changes also reflected in `firstLink` variable?

### EDIT:

As pointed out in comments and answer, I understand that object variable are reference variables and that more than one variable can refer to the same Object. Consequently changes in values to any one of the referencing variable would affect other variables to the same reference too.

In the above example, after executing`previousLink.next = currentLink.next` line, `currentLink` is also removed from `firstLink`, as both `previousLink` and `firstLink` point to same Object. Similarly, when `currentLink = currentLink.next` is executed why doesn't it have any effect on `firstLink`?

Comment: Can you be more specific by what you mean when you say "the changes also reflected in `firstLink` variable"? What changes?

Comment: The key point to realise is that all Java object variables are _reference_ variables, which behave a little like pointers in C or C++.  An object is never _stored in_ a variable - it's _referred to_ by a variable.  And the important point here is that often, two or more variables refer to the same object.

Comment: True, but then when we execute statement `currentLink = currentLink.next`, then nothing happens in the `firstLink` variable. How is that?

Comment: Slight kink, the JLS (Java Language Specification) defines reference variables as pointers to objects. Java doesn't support programmatic pointer manipulation other than assignment and dereferencing (dot operator). Suppose you remove a node that is pointed to by `firstLink.next`. Your loop has `previousLink` pointing to the same object as `firstLink`. Both pointers are pointing to the same link. So whatever happens in the object, the other pointer to the same object can detect.

Comment: Well,  because `currentLink = currentLink.next;` doesn't change any objects at all.  It changes the `currentLink` variable, to make it refer to a (generally) different object.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that variables are nothing else other than named references to places in memory.

Let's assume that `firstLink` points to some `Link` object in memory

[image: firstLink]

Then, when you say

```
Link currentLink = firstLink;
Link previousLink = firstLink;
```

You are pointing `currentLink` and `previousLink` to that same object in memory. Now you have 3 differently named references to the same object.

[image: three links]

This means that, after this assignment, unless any of the variables are pointed to another place in memory, changes to any of them will be reflected in the other two.

Comment: Thanks for a neat illustration. But then why doesn't anything happen to `firstLink` when we execute `currentLink = currentLink.next`

Comment: Because, that statement isn't modifying `firstLink`. What it does is points `currentLink` to the same place where `currentLink.next` is pointing to. You can imagine that the arrow coming out of `currentLink` moves to the same place the arrow coming out of `currentLink.next` is pointing to.

Comment: Try to think of every variable as an arrow pointing to some data in memory and the name of the variable is the name of that arrow, not the name of the actual data it's pointing to. When you say `variable1 = variable2`, you are saying "point `variable1` to whatever `variable2` is pointing to`. Only the arrows are being changed, the actual data isn't.

Comment: But, as you mentioned all the three variables, `firstLink`, `currentLink` and `previousLink` point to same `Link` in memory. So when `currentLink`points to `currentLink.next`, then this should also makes changes to `firstLink`

Comment: No it shouldn't because `currentLink.next` is pointing to something else, not `firstLink`. All that is changing in that statement is what `currentLink` is pointing to. Nothing is affecting `firstLink` or the data it points to.

Answer (score 0):

> After executing the statement previousLink.next = currentLink.next in
>   that method, why are the changes also reflected in firstLink variable?

This has already been answered well, but for completeness: because setting a value on the object locally pointed to by `previousLink` changes the state of that object on the heap, and any other local variables pointing to it will see those changes. 
To put it in real-world terms: Suppose you know Mr. Jones as Bob and I know him as Robert. If you object to something Bob says and punch him in the face, I will see that Robert has a black eye.

> when currentLink = currentLink.next is executed why doesn't it have
>   any effect on firstLink?

Because here we're simply assigning a value to a local variable. We have set `currentLink` to point to the next node along the chain - this is a purely local change. It's only when we take some action affecting the state of `currentLink` that reference comes into play (at that point, we are changing the state of an object on the heap)

Comment: Interestingly i notice that whenever the value of instance variables of the class are changed, the change is propogated across all variables referencing the same object i.e. in this case if we modify `bookName` or `millionsSold` or `next` present in class `Link`, then the change also effects other variables like `firstLink` and `preivousLink`.  But when the change is made to entire variable, like this `currentLink = currentLink.next` nothing happens.

Comment: Exactly. When you set the local variable to a new value, this only affects the local context. `current = current.next` only affects the value of the local variable `current`. The state of the object it used to point to is not affected by this operation. When you take an action that affects the state of an objects, for example `current.next=next.next` (to excise a link from the list) this affects the state of the object that `current` currently points to.

Comment: The confusion is probably due to the fact that we're using the same symbol for assignment in two very different cases. As a thought experiment, imagine a language just like java, except that local assignment is done by some sort of `set .. to` statement, something like `set current to next` and state changes are always done by methods on their targets: `current.set_next(next.next)`. This might help you distinguish between the two operations.